# Swift Converting Epoch Time to Local Time

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

How do I convert epochTime to current local time? Essentially, in below codes, how do I get 1 and 2 to produce the same time?

```
var epochTime = (NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)

//1. Convert epochTime to NSDate(). Shows "2016-06-14 22:47:23 +0000\n"
print(NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: epochTime))

//2. local time using NSDate(). Shows "Jun 14, 2016, 6:47 PM"
NSDate()
```

Comment: The dates are same (timezones are different), why do you need to do that?

Comment: Yeah, those dates are the same. If you need them to print differently, use `NSDateFormatter`.